# Android intent extra populate

Tags: java, android, serialization

Fisrt i must mention that i am new to Android and Java. I coded a json http object who populate Serializable class and from them i populate listviews, everything works fine, but now i am trying to populate a textview which is on different xml layout, with one string from Serializable class.

Serializable class

```
    public class FeedItem   implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     private int test1;
    private String title;
    private String date;
    private String attachmentUrl;
    private String id;
    private String content;
    private String url;
    private String tiitle = "sfsf";




    public String getUrl() {
            return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
    }

    public String getContent() {
            return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
    }

    public String getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
            return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDate() {
            return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
    }

    public String getAttachmentUrl() {
            return attachmentUrl;
    }

    public void setAttachmentUrl(String attachmentUrl) {
            this.attachmentUrl = attachmentUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "[ title=" + title + ", date=" + date + "]";



    }


      public void save(){
FeedItem feed = new FeedItem();

 Intent intent =  new Intent();
 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    intent.putExtra("title", feed);
```

and the fragment class where i want to populate textview

```
public void UpdateList(){
  TextView infoz = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.infoz);
      Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String title = (String) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("title");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}

The toast is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a Serializable object in your Bundle (in Eclipse, moving your mouse above the method name should show you the signature, which in your case would be putExtra(String name, Serializable extra)). To retrieve the title String, you should first retrieve the FeedItem object, then get the String from it, like so :

```
intent.putExtra("title", feed);
```

and

```
String title = ((FeedItem)getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("title")).getTitle();
```

Alternatively, you could just put the title in the extra, if that's all you need, using

```
intent.putExtra("title", feed.getTitle());
```

then getting the title like this :

```
String title = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
```

Comment: First method force closes and second still empty toast, I trying to work this out for 3 days...

Comment: The force close is hard to debug if you don't give the stacktrace, or at least the name of the error and indicate where it fails. As for the empty toast, my guess is your mistake is elsewhere. It's not clear how the save method is used just like this, it looks incomplete), but if it is used in the FeedItem class, it's normal you feed is empty because I'm guessing you're not using that intent to start an Activity yet you retrieve the intent in the Fragment using the getIntent method of an Activity ...

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you are using to get the title from the intent:

```
String title = (String) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("title");
```

This will extract the extra with the key "title" and deserialize it, but you are then casting this to a `String`. You didn't put a `String` into the extras `Bundle`, you put a `FeedItem` object in there. You need to do this:

```
FeedItem feedItem = (FeedItem)getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("title");
String title = feedItem.getTitle();
```

Also, this code you posted:

```
public void save(){
    FeedItem feed = new FeedItem();
    Intent intent =  new Intent();
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    intent.putExtra("title", feed);
```

makes no sense. First, you create a new instance of `FeedItem`. This new instance will have an empty `title`. Secondly, you create a `Bundle` called `extras` but do nothing with it. And thirdly, are you sure that the `Intent` you are sending actually has the object you want in the extras? Either check this with a debugger or debug logging.